# How can I set a tag when pulling a Docker image?

Tags: docker

Occasionally, I want to set a useful short name for an image I pull. Right now, my only option is to find out the Docker image's digest and use that.

Thus, currently I have to follow the following workflow:

```bash
docker pull custom.artifactory.com/group/image-name:v2.7.1
# manually look for the digest
docker tag <fully qualified image name>|<digest> short-name
docker run short-name
```

I would like to tag right when I pull the image:

```
# Intended usage, but does not work!
docker pull custom.artifactory.com/group/image-name:v2.7.1 --tag short-name
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Why do you need to look up the digest? If I understood you correctly, the second step could simply be `docker tag custom.artifactory.com/group/image-name:v2.7.1 short-name`. (Re-) tagging while pulling is not possible.

Comment: I have to admit, using the name only appeared to me when writing this question. Nevertheless, it is a second step I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no way to tag the image being pulled from within the pull command itself; you will, as you noted, have to run `docker tag` command after `docker pull`.

However, looking at the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/), you can reference the docker image by name, rather than by the digest. This would save you having to look up the digest if you are already using the name to pull the image.